# How to get data in laravel joins?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I am using join in laravel with mutiples and different conditions but I have a problem the quantity and the date column is always null but when I see in the database the column is not null it has some value it is only null when I am using join.

```
$contact_packages = Contact::where('contacts.id','!=',1)
        ->leftJoin('transactions as t','t.id','=','contacts.id')
        ->leftJoin('transaction_sell_lines as tsl','tsl.transaction_id','=','t.id') 
        ->join('customer_package as cp','contacts.id','=','cp.contact_id')
        ->join('package as p','cp.package_id','=','p.id')
        ->join('customer_package_service as cps','cps.customer_package_id','=','cp.id')    
        ->leftJoin('categories as c','p.category_id','=','c.id')
        ->leftJoin('categories as sc','p.sub_category_id','=','sc.id')            
        // ->where('cps.customer_package_id','cp.id')      
        ->select([
            'contacts.id as cid',
            'contacts.name as cname',
            'p.id as pid',
            'p.name as pname',
            DB::raw('TRIM(tsl.quantity)+0 as pqty'),
            // 'tsl.quantity as pqty',               
            DB::raw('count(cps.product_id) as services'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN cps.status = 0 THEN cps.product_id END) as pending'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN cps.status = 1 THEN cps.product_id END) as redeemed'), 
            't.created_at as date',               
            'c.name as pc',
            'sc.name as psc',               
            'p.expire_days as ped',  
            'cps.customer_package_id as cpid'                           
       ])
        ->groupBy('cpid')
        ->get();
```

```
 select `contacts`.`id` as `cid`, `contacts`.`name` as `cname`, 
        `p`.`id` as `pid`, `p`.`name` as `pname`, 
        TRIM(tsl.quantity)+0 as pqty, count(cps.product_id) as services, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN cps.status = 0 THEN cps.product_id END) as pending, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN cps.status = 1 THEN cps.product_id END) as redeemed, 
        `t`.`created_at` as `date`, `c`.`name` as `pc`, 
        `sc`.`name` as `psc`, `p`.`expire_days` as `ped`, 
        `cps`.`customer_package_id` as `cpid` from `contacts` 
    left join `transactions` as `t` on `t`.`id` = `contacts`.`id` 
    left join `transaction_sell_lines` as `tsl` on `tsl`.`transaction_id` = `t`.`id` 
    inner join `customer_package` as `cp` on `contacts`.`id` = `cp`.`contact_id` 
    inner join `package` as `p` on `cp`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` 
    inner join `customer_package_service` as `cps` on `cps`.`customer_package_id` = `cp`.`id` 
    left join `categories` as `c` on `p`.`category_id` = `c`.`id` 
    left join `categories` as `sc` on `p`.`sub_category_id` = `sc`.`id` 
where `contacts`.`id` != ? 
and `contacts`.`deleted_at` is null 
group by `cpid`
```

Comment: Which one? Or both? `\`t`.`created_at\`` or `\`p`.`expire_days\``

Comment: t.created_at and tsl.quantity

Comment: What are the data types of those 2 fields

Comment: `t.created_at is timestamps and tsl.quantity is integer

Comment: Why are you TRIMing an integer

Comment: because in the database it goes like 1.0000 anyway I have solved it thank you for your time sir

Comment: Then its not defined as an integer

Comment: I am getting it right but now 
 DB::raw('count(cps.product_id) as services'),
I am not getting desired quantity it is giving wrong data

Comment: I think you need to start by showing us the table definitions for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240854/discussion-between-usman-ali-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put the foreign name in first join I put the primary key which is wrong.

```
$contact_packages = Contact::where('contacts.id','!=',1)
    ->leftJoin('transactions as t','t.contact_id','=','contacts.id')
    ->leftJoin('transaction_sell_lines as tsl','tsl.transaction_id','=','t.id') 
    ->join('customer_package as cp','contacts.id','=','cp.contact_id')
    ->join('package as p','cp.package_id','=','p.id')
    ->join('customer_package_service as cps','cps.customer_package_id','=','cp.id')    
    ->leftJoin('categories as c','p.category_id','=','c.id')
    ->leftJoin('categories as sc','p.sub_category_id','=','sc.id')            
    // ->where('cps.customer_package_id','cp.id')      
    ->select([
        'contacts.id as cid',
        'contacts.name as cname',
        'p.id as pid',
        'p.name as pname',
        DB::raw('TRIM(tsl.quantity)+0 as pqty'),
        // 'tsl.quantity as pqty',               
        DB::raw('count(cps.product_id) as services'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN cps.status = 0 THEN cps.product_id END) as pending'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN cps.status = 1 THEN cps.product_id END) as redeemed'), 
        't.created_at as date',               
        'c.name as pc',
        'sc.name as psc',               
        'p.expire_days as ped',  
        'cps.customer_package_id as cpid'                           
   ])
    ->groupBy('cpid')
    ->get();
```